# Error trying to output the Eloquent relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm getting the error "Trying to get property 'company_name' of non-object". I studied about the Eloquent relationship and try to implement in my code. But it gives me that error in the view (products.show)

Which part are wrong?

Is it okay to have many different relationship to other model as well?

In 'Vendor Model':

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'roc_no';
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

In 'Product Model':

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function vendor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendor');
}
```

In 'User Model':

```
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Vendor');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_users');
    }
```

In the 'products.show':

```
...    
{!! $product->description !!}
<!-- The error is at $product->vendor->company_name -->
Company Name: <a href="/vendors/{{ $product->vendor_roc_no }}">{{ $product->vendor->company_name }}</a>
```

In 'ProductController':

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'slug' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->slug = $request->slug;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->vendor_roc_no = auth()->user()->vendor->roc_no;
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/account/products')->with('success', 'Product added successfully.');
    }

    public function show(Product $product)
    {    
        return view('products.show')->with('product', $product);
    }
```

Updated:
In vendors table:

```
Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('company_name');
            $table->string('roc_no');
            $table->string('company_address');
            $table->string('company_tel');
            $table->string('company_fax')->nullable();
            $table->string('company_email');
            $table->string('company_website')->nullable();
            $table->string('company_logo')->nullable();
            $table->text('company_profile')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

In products table:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('vendor_roc_no');
            $table->timestamps();

            // $table->foreign('vendor_id')->references('id')->on('vendors');
        });
```

Comment: Seems like you have at least one vendor does not have a vendor associated with it.  You should check that vendor exists before trying to use it.  If you are using Laravel 5.5+ you may find the [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) function handy.

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry, I'm still new and have less experience in Laravel and framework. I think the relationship definition is correct, right? Oh, when I'm using the helper optional() it returns null instead of error.

Comment: I think it isn't, but it's hard to say without seeing the tables. Try this: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendor', 'vendor_roc_no');`

Comment: @devk still not working. I've updated the question.

Comment: Try `return $this->belongsTo('App\Vendor', 'vendor_roc_no', 'roc_no');`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. :) Now I noticed that in the docs. It is hard to understand those fancy terms in that docs, btw.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you'll need to establish the relationship for accessing properties from the other model, so in this case, you want to get the company_name that is on the vendor for this you'll need to tell your model to bring vendor. Example:

```
$user->with('anyRelation')->get();
// Then you can use like, $user->anyRelation->property;
```

Now I noticed something in your show method, you're sending Product class but not an eloquent object maybe just using Eloquent would help? Example

```
$products = Product:all(); // this would return every record on your db
return view('products.show')->with('products', $products);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: I learned [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50430636/laravel-5-6-errorexception-trying-to-get-property-slug-of-non-object) when using model binding it is not necessarily to query the records. And I tried if I'm changed as you mention, it also gives error :(

Comment: could be possible that `company_name` is not an object property but instead an array? so it would be like `$product->vendor['company_name']` just guessing a bit here

Comment: I think none of both, because the `company_name` returns null.

Comment: could you print whatever `$product->vendor` has? this may help to see what is inside. 

Another idea im getting is simply try to query vendor by itself and see what you get from it, could be that the model is not working correctly or something :)

Comment: Problem solved. I did it as @JonasStaudenmeir mentioned. Thanks for helping, btw. :)