# property does not exist but relationship established

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, class, relationship

I'm trying to get an attribute from a table but it tells me that it doesn't exist:

My View is :

```
@foreach ($weeklyTicketsclosed as $ticket)
  @if($ticket->statut=='fermé')
    <tr>
    <td>{{ $ticket->societe}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->intervenant}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->assistance->level}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->message}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->urgence->niveau}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->statut}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->utilisateur->name}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket-> created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{ $ticket->gestions->observations}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endif
  @endforeach
```

My Tickets class is :

```
class Tickets extends Model
{
    protected $table="tickets";
    protected $fillable=['message','utilisateur_id','urgence_id','societe','typeassistance','intervenant'];

    public function urgence()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\Urgence::class);
    }
    public function gestions()
    {
      return $this->hasMany(\App\Gestion::class, 'utilisateur_id');
    }
    public function assistance()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\assistance::class, 'typeassistance', 'id');
    }
```

My Gestion class is :

```
class Gestion extends Model
{
    protected $table="gestions";
    protected $fillable=['description','duree','ticket_id','utilisateur_id','observations'];

    public function tickets(){
      return $this->belongsTo(\App\Tickets::class);
    }
}
```

The console returns a does not exist error on ticket->gestions->observations.
I can't seem to find where it comes from, the relationship between Gestion and Tickets classes is done the same way as the relationship between Tickets and Urgence or Tickets and Assistance.

Error : Property [observations] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rmstickets\resources\views\export\ticketsexcelferme.blade.php)

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ticket has many Gestions, so `$ticket->gestions` is really an array/collection of objects. You'll want to iterate through it, or just get the first one:

```
<td>
  @foreach($ticket->gestions as $gestion)
  {{ $gestion->observations}}
  @endforeach
</td>
```

Or

```
<td>{{ $ticket->gestions->first()->observations}}</td>
```

Comment: First one : ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined offset: 1     Second one :ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'observations' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rmstickets\resources\views\export\ticketsexcelferme.blade.php)

Comment: Interesting offset message, but I do notice I made a typo. It should be `$gestion->observations`

Comment: The second should work, but may throw an error if there are no gestions for that ticket. So you may need to see if there are any gestions before you try to print out the observations.

Comment: Is there a way i can prevent that error using an if clause or something before the <td> ?

Comment: Sure, just use `@if($ticket->gestions->count())`

Comment: returns empty value, when it's clearly not empty. No more error tho.

Comment: Are you sure that the table should be joined on `utilisateur_id` and not `ticket_id`?

Comment: Oh yeah it works you're right, sorry ! Thanks for your time and effort ! You're awesome !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Sorry to ask again, is there a way i can take the last observation instead of first()?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to have `last()`, but you can instead use `->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, returns error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\rmstickets\resources\views\export\ticketsexcelferme.blade.php). I wrote like this : {{ $ticket->gestions->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()->observations}}

Comment: Ah ha, try `$ticket->gestions()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first()->observations}}`. I can never remember when it needs the parenthesis.

Comment: Wow, you're actually so good! Thanks again! Have a wonderful day, Sir !

Answer (score 0):

this looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451895/error-trying-to-output-the-eloquent-relationship-in-laravel/50452487)
 the solution for this was tell laravel which fields belong in the other model. I hope this helps :)